# AngularFire login with google, using parameters

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

we are using this code to login with google:

```js
var googleOptions = {
    scope: 'email'
};

$scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google", googleOptions).then(function(authData) {
    console.log(authData.google.email);

    var userSigninIdentifier = authData.google.id;

    console.log("userSigninIdentifier:" + userSigninIdentifier);

    if ($scope.googleRef.$getRecord(userSigninIdentifier) == null) {
        console.warn("new user, registering...");
        $scope.register(authProvider, authData);
    } else {
        $scope.profileID = $scope.googleRef.$getRecord(userSigninIdentifier).profileID;
        $firebase(ref.child("users").child("signin").child("google").child(userSigninIdentifier)).$update({
            token: authData.token,
            expires: authData.expires,
            AccessToken: authData.google.accessToken
        });
        $firebase(ref.child("users").child("data").child($scope.profileID)).$update({
            displayName: authData.google.displayName,
            email: authData.google.email,
            picture: authData.google.cachedUserProfile.picture
        });
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        $state.go('app.home');
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Authentication failed google:", error);
});
```

Unfortunately, the options don't work. And since the options don't work, we can't access the users email adress. How do we use AngularFire's $authWithOAuthPopup method with parameters?

Edit: this (in a slightly different form) works perfectly with facebook login

Comment: There's a lot of things going on in this code. Is the question only about the return value of authData? What is $scope.googleRef and where is that declared? Is that code superfluous?

Comment: Using the provided `{ scope: 'email' }` option should definitely work and I am able to verify that locally on my machine. In order for us to help you debug this, please provide a JSFiddle or Plunkr with a working reproduction of the issue. Ideally, you would remove the unnecessary code after the `console.log(authData.google.email)` call in the repro so it is easier for us to debug.